# Is it bad practice to call OAuth2.0 password flow for every request?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm using an API with OAuth2.0 protocol in my backend environment with password flow (grant_type = "password").
I chose this flow because I don't have user interaction, it is just machine to machine (M2M).
I know there is another flow, "client_credentials" I think that is more appropriate but the API provider doesn't offer this option.

So, sometimes my system makes 5 request in an hour, sometimes none an hour, this makes me ask as the title says, is it bad to call the password flow for every request?
Should I use the refresh token, another possibility or does it just not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard behaviour is for your API to work like this:

- Authenticate with the Authorization Server to provide a credential and get an access token (which may live for 60 minutes)
- Cache the token in the client process (your API) - perhaps in a thread safe memory cache
- Call the downstream API with the access token as frequently as you like (eg every 30 seconds)

This ensures that:

- The credential is not sent often and on most calls only an access token is sent
- When the credential is sent, only the Authorization Server can see it - not the downstream API
- The risk of stolen credentials is lower - and if an access token is somehow stolen it will expire soon anyway

Sometimes you may have to work with non standards based APIs. In this case I would still aim to follow the above pattern as best you can.

Comment: When you say cache the token in thread safe memory cache, can this be done with nodejs ? I'm not familiarized with memory cache.

Comment: You can just use a variable in node, since it is single threaded

Comment: Ah understood, makes sense. Thanks!